# A random hash symbol is showing in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is an image of my HTML: [image]

There is nothing in my javascript file indicating it appends this hash here. I'm not sure why it is there. Any idea?

Comment: How should one guess where the hash symbol is coming from when you don't even tell us where the rest of your HTML is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Who wrote that html? it seems someone is trying to save a place to add something later in that space? i think  if you call the function in that hash whatever you want to archive will jump for that part of the page...usually # used to add links to elements or to name anchors.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Once you get enough reputation, you'll be able to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue working on my Ruby on Rails app. Turned out I accidentally tried to comment out a line in my html.erb view with a hash symbol (#), how you'd normally do it in pure Ruby and that was causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, the answer could benefit from more detailed information, especially including relevant code snippets to illustrate the solution. Providing step-by-step instructions along with code examples will make your answer more comprehensive and valuable to both the original poster and future visitors facing a similar issue. Your efforts to enhance the answer are appreciated!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).